# Finding a specific set of first two words of long string

Tags: php, regex

Right now I have a check in place that analyzes the first word of a string like so:

```
if( strtolower( stristr(  preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', trim($sql) ), ' ', true )  ) == 'select'){ //do something }
```

Now I would like to check for the first two words to be ==  strtolower('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS')
However my original code only analyzes the very first word. How can I fix this?

Comment: you could use your regex above to sanitize spacing and then explode(' ', $value) and check elements 0 and 1 if count >= 2

Comment: I thought the preg_replace removes everything after the first space?

Comment: give it a try - your preg_replace replaces >1 whitespace characters ( \s+ ) with a single space globally across the string. After this it would be safe to explode around a single space

Comment: I see what you mean :) I forgot that, this is what I was doing with that regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions seems overkill for this task, you can just use strpos to check if a string containing the two words is at the start of the string you're checking (position 0),

```
if (strpos(strtolower($sql), "select sql_calc_found_rows") === 0) { ... }
```

Comment: hmm... that is simplier but it doesn't seem to be working. converted it to :: if (strpos(strtolower($sql), strtolower('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS')) === 0) {

Comment: @Mallow Oops, I had a typo in the string "sql_cal_found_rows", should've been "calc" not "cal". I've updated my answer to fix it. You don't need the "strtolower('SELECT...)" just put it in lowercase to begin with.

Comment: yeah I put it back because of the typo, but with or without the typo it isn't acting as expected. Let me check my input string... Yeah they are the same. Something is missing...?

Comment: @Mallow What's your input string? There might be whitespace at the beginning which needs removing first? Try "trim(strtolower($sql))" instead of "strtolower($sql)". Or maybe there's more than one space between "SELECT" and "SQL..." ?

Comment: Hazaah, that worked. Yeah my input string is formatted for my personal readability so it looks like $var['sql'] = ' {carrage return} SELECT {carrage return}{tab} Column Name, {carrage return}{tab} etc...